# Only include needed polyfills with babel-polyfill

Tags: babeljs, polyfills, babel-polyfill, tree-shaking

Is there a way to "tree shake" babel-polyfill, such that only the features I use are polyfilled?

That is, if I never use `String.padStart` in my code, it's polyfill should not be included.

Comment: I would also like to know this.  I'm even ok with a good CLI i can run on occasion to figure out all the requires like `require('core-js/fn/array/some');` i would need to add

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using CoreJS 3 (beta) `core-js@3.0.0-beta.3`.
Babel polyfill also uses `core-js` so I think you can use below method:

```
npm install --save core-js@3.0.0-beta.3
```

Then in your JS code you can import your desired polyfills as below (ES syntax):

```
import "core-js/features/array/includes";
import "core-js/features/string/starts-with";
```

So far it's working great for me!